# Expanding shell variable in sed in remote host

Tags: linux, sed

The sed command, which is run locally looks like this (it works fine):

```
sed -i "\|$IFM_MOUNT|d" /opt/genApp.cfg
```

However, if i try t run the same in a remote host doing an ssh, it gives me issue:

```
ssh root@$host  'sed -i "\|$IFM_MOUNT|d" /opt/genApp.cfg'
Password:
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: `IFM_MOUNT` does not appear to be set in the remote shell. (If you want to take it from the local shell: the single quotes prevent its expansion in the local shell)

Comment: @Wintermute: I can't use two double quotes nested as well.

Comment: You won't need the remote double quotes if the variable is already expanded though, right?  You could just use outer double quotes and inner single quotes then

Comment: You could use `\"` inside double quotes, but if it were me, I'd put the quotes the other way around, i.e. `ssh root@"$host" "sed -i '\\|$IFM_MOUNT|d' /opt/genApp.cfg"` -- to the local shell, the single quotes are just part of a doubly-quoted string, so it'll expand `$IFM_MOUNT`, and the remote shell doesn't actually have to expand anything, so single quotes are fine there. Unless `IFM_MOUNT` contains strange things.

Comment: Thanks a lot...this one solved as u said: `ssh root@$host  "sed -i '\|$IFM_MOUNT|d' /opt/genApp.cfg"` u can add an please for people's benefit and i will change the subject line to expanding shell variables in sed in remote host

Comment: Sorry, real life interrupted. I added an answer; it ended up somewhat longer than I initially expected. Do make sure you read the **Caveats** section; it contains rather important information about the ways this sort of thing can go horribly wrong (especially with a remote root shell). How important it is for your case depends on who controls the `IFM_MOUNT` variable, so you'll have to decide that for yourself (I don't know it), but either way the risks of this approach are something every shell scripter should know and keep in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Variable Expansion

The problem you're encountering has to do with shell expansion in strings. There are two relevant categories of strings:

- singly-quoted (surrounded by `'`), in which variables are not expanded, and
- doubly-quoted (surrounded by `"`), in which they are, and in which a number of special characters (such as `$`) need to be escaped to retain their literal meaning.

#### Arthur "Two Shells" Jackson (scnr)

In your case, there are two shells involved that can expand variables: the local shell and the remote shell (that the remote `sshd` spawns for you). So let's break it down: with the command

```
ssh root@$host 'sed -i "\|$IFM_MOUNT|d" /opt/genApp.cfg'
```

the local shell sees the singly-quoted string `'sed -i "\|$IFM_MOUNT|d" /opt/genApp.cfg'`. Because it is a singly-quoted string, variable expansion does not happen, and this string is passed verbatim to the remote shell. The remote shell, accordingly, sees the command

```
sed -i "\|$IFM_MOUNT|d" /opt/genApp.cfg
```

Here, `"\|$IFM_MOUNT|d"` is a doubly-quoted string, and the shell accordingly expands `$IFM_MOUNT`. Because `$IFM_MOUNT` does not have a value in the remote shell, the replacement is the empty string, so the command ends up as

```
sed -i "\||d" /opt/genApp.cfg
```

...whereupon `sed` sees the code `\||d`, which leads to the error you see (an empty regex clause in `sed` code reattempts the most recently attempted regex, which only works if a most recently attempted regex exists).

#### Solution (read the Caveats section below!)

Since it appears that you want to replace `$IFM_MOUNT` with the value it has in the *local* shell rather than the remote one, the most straightforward fix is to switch the quotation marks around, i.e.

```
ssh "root@$host" "sed -i '\\|$IFM_MOUNT|d' /opt/genApp.cfg"
```

Now the local shell sees a doubly-quoted string `"sed -i '\\|$IFM_MOUNT|d' /opt/genApp.cfg"` into which it dutifully substitutes `$IFM_MOUNT`, which means that the remote shell sees something like `sed -i '\|/mnt/ifm|d' /opt/genApp.cfg` (if `$IFM_MOUNT` was `/mnt/ifm`).

#### Notes

The escaped backslash is not strictly necessary in this particular case, but since there are contexts in which backslashes need to be escaped in doubly-quoted strings (e.g., `"\\$foo"`) to retain their literal meaning, I consider it a good habit to do it all the time when I mean to retain the literal meaning of a backslash.

Also, expanding shell variables outside double quotes is rarely a good idea (because the shell will split the expanded string if it contains whitespace<sup>1</sup>), so I took the liberty of putting `"root@$host"` between double quotes to prevent splitting. It is unlikely to work if `$host` contains whitespace, but this way it will fail in a more predictable manner if such broken input appears.

<sup>1</sup> More precisely: Anything in `$IFS`, which means space, tab, and newline unless you fiddled with `IFS`.

## Caveats (read this!)

Caveats to consider: There are two substitutions of text into code here, both of which carry the risk of code injection.

First, since `$IFM_MOUNT` is substituted directly into shell code, it can be used to inject shell commands into the remote shell. Consider, for example, a case in which

```
IFM_MOUNT="/mnt/ifm|d' /opt/genApp.cfg; rm -Rf /; #"
```

The remote (root!) shell would see

```
sed -i '\|/mnt/ifm|d' /opt/genApp.cfg; rm -Rf /; #|d' /opt/genApp.cfg
```

That is not a good thing for it to see.

Second, the `sed` code also carries a possibility of code injection, particularly if GNU sed is on the other side (it can execute shell code). It seems hardly consequential in this case, where shell commands can be injected directly, but consider for the purpose of completeness the case that

```
IFM_MOUNT='/mnt/ifm|!d; #'
```

Whereupon the remote shell would see

```
sed -i '\|/mnt/ifm|!d; #|d' /opt/genApp.cfg
```

...which would throw out everything *except* the lines you wanted thrown out. It becomes worse with GNU sed and the likes of `IFM_MOUNT='/mnt/ifm/|!d; e rm -Rf/; #`, but again, there already is a way to inject shell commands, so it doesn't really matter in this case.

What this means is that **`IFM_MOUNT` should not come from an untrustworthy source,** and you should be damn sure it doesn't contain any characters you don't expect.